# why does this compile?

Tags: scala

Why does this compile:

```
scala> def last[A](a : List[A] ) : A =     
 | a match {                           
 |   case head :: Nil => Some(head) get
 |   case _ :: tail => last(tail)      
 |   case Nil => None get              
 | }                   

last: [A](a: List[A])A
```

While this obviously doesn't:

```
scala> None get

java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:262)
at .<init>(<console>:6)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at RequestResult$.<init>(<console>:9)
at RequestResult$.<clinit>(<console>)
at RequestResult$scala_repl_result(<console>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(Interpreter.scala:988)
at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(Interpreter.scala:988)
at scala.util.control.Exception$C...
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The latter code does compile and fails just at *runtime* - what you see is an exception, not a compiler error. `None` inherits from `Option` and thus must define the method `get`.

EDIT:
The question could be rephrased as "why does the compiler accept a clearly stupid call to `None.get`?". This question is indeed nontrivial to answer, so I'll spend a few more words on it at different levels.

- First a clarification: to understand the difference between compile-time and run-time errors, it is probably instructive to create a Scala program containing the code you want to test, compile it and test it. If you run code only at the prompt, it becomes harder for a beginner to appreciate the difference between a compile-time error and a run-time error.
  Still, the savvy user will learn to recognize the different format of the errors.
- **Isn't a method like `get` stupid, since it can fail at runtime?** Indeed, when you have a value `v` of type `Option[T]`, you should usually pattern match on it or use methods like `getOrElse`, `map`, and so on: methods which work even if `v` is empty. But sometimes you have such a value and are already sure that `v` must be `Some(q)`: get should only be used then.
- **Why, given the definition of None, cannot the compiler give a compile-time error?**
  The compiler gives an error when you call a method which is not defined on the receiver object, but `get` is defined on the `Option` class, and therefore on its two subclasses, `Some` and `None`. It is only its body that contains a call to error.
- **Why does the given definitions of `Option` make sense?** For the user to be call to call `get` when he wants to, it must be defined on `Option`. Otherwise one would need a typecast before being able to call it - at that point, it'd be easier to just do pattern matching.
- **Why doesn't still the compiler recognize that the code is going to fail at runtime?**
  Because recognizing the nontrivial cases is hard. For instance, in the function you posted above, it is not clear that `None.get` is ever going to be executed; moreover, the code you gave will give a run-time error if you pass in an empty list; therefore it is a correct implementation of the usual specification of last. In general, you might have `v get` and it might be nontrivial to understand whether `v` might or might not be `None`. There are other tools which try to find this kind of bugs (not sure if any for Scala yet), but they also tend to give either false negatives or false positives: they might report problems which cannot happen, or miss relevant problems. In the end, you really don't want their output to be together the output of the Scala compiler.
  Having some basic easy checks within the compiler might make sense, but there you have an engineering question: it's not clear if the extra code is worth its cost.

Comment: Just to add if you run: last(Nil) you'll get the same runtime failure

Comment: It seems there's more to the story here that I obvoiusly don't understand (not sure if I deserver two downvotes for ignorance). But why doesn't the compiler check to see if None has a method called get? why is that left till runtime? I'm sure I'm just asking to get flamed for this question but it would help me if someone could explain why my reasoning is inaccurate.

Comment: I had guessed the source of the confusion and I tried to address it in my answer - but I'll try to spell it out more clearly.

Comment: i think this answer is terrible.  it doesn't explain anything, just gives a lot of handwaving.  for example, what does "it is not clear that None.get is ever going to be executed" have to do with static analysis?  absolutely nothing.

Comment: Thanks for explaining your downvote (assuming the one I got was from you). Formally, "None get" is type-correct thus valid at compile-time. The last point of my answer discusses why it is not trivial to build a tool trying to predict which run-time errors are going to happen; such tools are called static analysis tools, and to reduce the number of false positives they try to predict whether a piece of code is going to be executed. Finally, while all the analyses done by a compiler are (by definition) static analyses, "static analysis" is not normally used for type-checking.